# Почему не обновляется количество страниц после фильтрации контента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Использую Vuex-хранилище для вытаскивания информации и расчета кол-ва страниц pageCount. После применения фильтра почему-то кол-во страниц не уменьшается и страница зависает. В консоли ошибка что-то типа несоответствие длины массива(из-за того что pageCount не обновился).

```
  computed:{
    pageCount(){
      return  Math.ceil(this.$store.getters.NEWS.length/5);
    }
  }
```

Причем при нажатии на фильтр обновляю хранилище новостей:

```
 methods:{
   onGetNews(){
       this.$store.dispatch('GET_NEWS', params);
       return this.$store.getters.NEWS;
   }
}
```

Comment: Сомнительно, что метод `onGetNews()` должен что-то возвращать. А так информации мало.

Comment: Почему странно? он возвращает фильтрованные новости. Это основная инфа. Действие GET_NEWS отрабатывает пормально, а вот pageCount не поспевает. Я видел что надо slice применять.

Comment: Метод `onGetNews` вызывает `action` `GET_NEWS`, тот в свою очередь (как правило) выполняет асинхронную операцию. А список новостей `this.$store.getters.NEWS` должен быть получен в вычисляемом поле.

Comment: GET_NEWS и выполняет асинхр.операцию. и какая разница вычисляемое свойство или метод в данном случае? При нажатии на фильтр вызывается метод onGetNews

Comment: Добавьте весь код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

предположу что у Вас выполняется на стороне `actions` асинхронная операция (ajax request), в результате необходимо ввести `Promise` и ожидать обновление данных. То что вы делаете в `onGetNews` не синхронизировано. Вы запускаете dispatch и после сразу return данные, хранилище на данный момент не синхронизировано! Решение:

В GET_NEWS возвращаете promise:

```
export function GET_NEWS({commit, state}, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //ajax
        axios.get(...).then((result) => {
            commit("SET_NEWS", result); //ну или что Вы там делаете)
            resolve(true);
        }).catch(e => {
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}
```

В onGetNews вы возвращаете return значит где-то его вызывает какой-то другой метод (в нем нужно вызвать .then() как в примере выше чтобы отследить выполнение операции). Поэтому он то же ожидает promise так как асинхронный, вернув данные к примеру использовав ES7 (верхний promise можно переписать так же, это всё для примера):

```
async onGetNews(){
   const result = await this.$store.dispatch('GET_NEWS', params);
   if (result) return this.$store.getters.NEWS;
```

}

Данный код сформирован исходя из данных которые Вы предоставили. Почему `pageCount` получает другой `length` не понятно, так как нет кода приложения. Но после получения `promise` длины массива будут совпадать!

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Попробую await добавить. А что значит "длины массива будут совпадать"? Какие длины вы подразумеваете и с чем совпадать они должны?

Comment: @obehanProger а Вы в вопросе писали что у вас ошибка возникает типо длины массивов не совпадают